# Best way to write InputStream to RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, io

Lets say I have a method

```
private int writeToFile(RandomAccessFile file, InputStream input) {
    int numberOfBytesWritten;
    //for now I have this :
    int data = in.read();
    while(data != -1) {
            //do something with data...
            numberOfBytesWritten += 1;
            f.write(data);
            data = in.read();
     }

    return numberOfBytesWritten;
}
```

I guess this is not the best way to write data to RAF. How can I do it better?

Comment: Use a `in.read(byte[])` to read more bytes at once (for example 8K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more if you like
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    numberOfBytesWritten += count;
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Why? The only way `read(byte[])` can return zero is if you supply a zero length buffer, which is (a) a coding error, and (b) not a condition you want to loop on.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev and (c) impossible with the answer given.